# Create embed code from Wowza Streaming Engine

Tags: video, embed, wowza

We are using Wowza streaming Engine Developer version right now. We are facing some issue in using wowza server. It will be very helpful you can suggest us in below points.

1. How can we add video in wowza? (We have uploaded video using ftp but how we can use it in wowza)
2. How to generate an embed code for a video?

Please help us. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Wowza world you usually have live streams and so called VOD (video on demand). In your case you need to upload your videos to the "content" directory in Wowza (just to keep things simple) and go into the Engine Manager and create a new so called "application" of type VOD. Actually Wowza ships with a default application called vod, so you can just tweak that one as well.

Embedding: there are many-many different free and commercial video players, one of the most popular ones is JW Player. You can find detailed information on their site, as well as an embed-code generator tool, which should help you.

Basically you need to give the video URL to JW Player, something that looks like this:

```
rtmp://yourserver:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4
```

Of course, the format depends on the streaming protocol you want to use (the above example is for RTMP, which works with Flash players, but generally not on mobile devices).

You can find an official and more detailed step-by-step [tutorial here](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?35-How-to-set-up-video-on-demand-streaming).